# Posting and retrieving a JSON object via REST call in java

Tags: post, curl, jersey, json

I have a Rest endpoint (jersey based) which accepts a JSON object which I retrieve by mapping it to a POJO, e.g

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void getResult(PojoClass pojo)
```

My PojoClass is:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class PojoClass {
private List<String> list;

public List<String> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<String> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
}
```

Now if I send a json data via curl command:

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json"  -i -X  'POST' -d @/tmp/xyz.json  http://127.0.0.1:8080/test
```

I am able to get it mapped properly into my PojoClass.

xvz.json is:

```
{
  "list":[
     "123",
     "456"
    ]
}
```

The list of PojoClass will have two elements ("123" and "456").

But if do a post call from JAVA. And I am sending the same json structure as payload, it is being received as a PojoClass with list as single element, which is a concatenation like ["123","456"]

I am using "HttpURLConnection" to make a post call from java.

Is something extra needed to get the same result as cURL command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a library conflict between JSONObject and JSONArray which was corrupting my JSON in request Payload.
When I handled this error, request went just fine and everything worked like charm.